# Matrix Transpose Reordering

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Say I have matrix product as follows:

$X.A$

where $X$ and $A$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $A$ is invertible.

Can all such products be represented as:

$B.X$

where $B$ is some $n\times n$ matrix and a transformed version of $A$?

(If not all, what conditions are needed for being able to do so?)

---

**NOTE**: I don't need a specific transformation to get to B. Just a proof that such a rearrangement is possible is enough.

---

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED**: I had begun by assuming $X.A = B.X$, and vectorizing both sides which leads to the following equation:

$\big[(A^T\otimes I_n ) - (I_n \otimes B)\big] vec(X) = 0_{n^2}$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

I haven't been able to go any further!

---

**EDIT 1**: Edited the question - $X$ is not necessarily invertible

**EDIT 2**: [Sylvester Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) is somewhat similar to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You want $$XA=BX$$

Solve for $B$ and you get $$ B=XAX^{-1}$$

if your matrices are invertible then there is no problem finding $B$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've made a mistake in the question - edit - $X$ is not necessarily invertible. Will edit the main question too.